Dataframe multi columns condition with groupby
I need to set a flag to 1 for every employee in the group (groupby MNGR, YEAR) if any of the employees in the group has any of the columns V1 or V2 or V3 or V4 is greater than 14.   I can make it work if only checking 1 column but the V columns can be more than 10 columns.
I have this code:
DF1['flg'] = [1 for i in range(1, 5) if DF1[f'V{i}'].gt(14).any().groupby(by=['MNGR', 'YEAR']).replace({True: 1, False: 0}).reindex_like(DF1) ]

But I got error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'groupby'

sample dataframes
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'EMPLID': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 'MNGR': ['BOB', 'JIM', 'RHONDA', 'RHONDA', 'JIM', 'RHONDA', 'RHONDA'], 'YEAR': [2012, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2012], 'V1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'V2': [2,3,4,50,6,7,8], 'V3': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 'V4': [7,15,8,9,10,11,12]})

Expected output:
  EMPLID    MNGR        YEAR  V1  V2  V3  V4     flg
0      12    BOB         2012   1  2   3   7       NaN
1      13    JIM         2013   2  3   3   15      1
2      14    RHONDA      2012   3  4   3   8       1
3      15    RHONDA      2012   4  50  3   9       1
4      16    JIM         2012   5  6   3   10      NaN
5      17    RHONDA      2013   6  7   3   11      NaN
6      18    RHONDA      2012   7  8   3   12      1


You can break this transformation into two discrete steps:

Find the rows where ANY V{1..4} columns are greater than 14
transform the groups ['MNGR', 'YEAR'] where ANY row meets the above

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'EMPLID': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
    'MNGR': ['BOB', 'JIM', 'RHONDA', 'RHONDA', 'JIM', 'RHONDA', 'RHONDA'],
    'YEAR': [2012, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2012],
    'V1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'V2': [2,3,4,50,6,7,8],
    'V3': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
    'V4': [7,15,8,9,10,11,12]
})

df['flag'] = (
    df.filter(regex=r'^V.+').gt(14).any(axis=1)          # 1.
    .groupby([df['MNGR'], df['YEAR']]).transform('any')  # 2.
    .astype(int)
)
print(df)
#    EMPLID    MNGR  YEAR  V1  V2  V3  V4  flag
# 0      12     BOB  2012   1   2   3   7     0
# 1      13     JIM  2013   2   3   3  15     1
# 2      14  RHONDA  2012   3   4   3   8     1
# 3      15  RHONDA  2012   4  50   3   9     1
# 4      16     JIM  2012   5   6   3  10     0
# 5      17  RHONDA  2013   6   7   3  11     0
# 6      18  RHONDA  2012   7   8   3  12     1

